# I want to bulk upload the resumes in zip file and extract the content of each resume in html5 and angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json, html

I have used the below service to extract and get the content of zip file. I want read the content of the files and put in the scope of the angular. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated. My function looks like this

```
.factory("extractAndParse", ["$q", function($q) {
    function unzip(zipfile) {
        var dfd = $q.defer();
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = dfd.reject.bind(dfd);
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            if (!reader.result) dfd.reject(new Error("Unknown error"));
                var zip = new JSZip(reader.result);
                var file = zip.files['CVLIST/Rabin.docx'];
                if (typeof file === 'undefined') {
                    dfd.reject(new Error('package.json does not exist'));
                }
                return dfd.resolve(file.asText());
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(zipfile);
            return dfd.promise;
        }

        function extractAndParse(zipfile) {
            return unzip(zipfile)
        }
        return extractAndParse;
}])
```

Now it says `.asText()` is not function.

Comment: What is asText() function? where it come from?

Comment: Which version of JSZip do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use here some standard function in place of `asText()`, like specified here:

https://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#APIASynch